# Fastest way of reading a file in Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, linux-kernel, memory-mapped-files

On Linux what would be the fastest way of reading a file in to an array of bytes/to process the bytes? This can include memory-mapping, sys calls etc. I am not familiar with the many Linux-specific functions.

In the past I have used boost memory mapping, but I need faster Linux-specific performance rather than portability.

Comment: `boost::iostreams` uses `mmap` on linux, you might see a small difference using it directly.

Comment: Perhaps you need readv(), this will allow you to gather data into bytes of array. See `man readv()` for details.

Answer (score 5):

`mmap` should be the fastest way to access the contents of a file if the file is large enough. There's an initial cost for setting up the memory mappings, but that's offset by not needing to copy the data from the page cache into userland. And if you want all the contents of the file, the cost to allocate the memory to your program should be more or less the same as the cost of `mmap`.

Your best bet, as always, is to test and benchmark.

Answer (score 2):

Don't let yourself get fooled by lazy stuff like memory mapping.  Rather focus on what you really need.  Do you really need to read the whole file into memory?  Then the straight-forward way of opening, reading chunks in a loop, and closing the file will be as fast as it can be done.

But often you don't really want that.  Instead you might want to read specific parts, a block here, a block there, jump through the file, read a block at a specific position, etc.

Then still `fseek`ing out those positions and `fread`ing the blocks won't have overheads worth mentioning.  But it can be more convenient to use memory mapping to let the operating system or a library deal with stuff like memory allocation etc.  It won't get the job done faster, though.

Comment: `mmap` should be faster on large enough files because you can avoid copying stuff from the page cache into userland. It's not "lazy stuff" at all. There should be no difference on random access since `mmap` doesn't actually read more data from the filesystem than any random seek/read. The only disadvantage of mmap might be the overhead of creating the mapping, but that shouldn't be that higher than what malloc will cause. Especially when you call malloc multiple times.

Comment: Well, memory mapping _can_ be implemented lazily of course (depends on the operating system), while reading file contents into a block of memory cannot (or at least that would be much more sophisticated and therefore unlikely).  The main aspect in my answer though was to point out that putting the whole file into memory probably does not make sense and should be reconsidered.

Comment: Concerning the mentioned advantage of avoiding copying stuff from page cache to userland:  Caching is a completely different aspect I wasn't addressing.  It only applies in case the user does read the file more than once; I interpreted the question as if it asked how to actually read the file as fast as possible (and read it actually).

Comment: No. Avoiding copying from the page cache is not a matter of reading it more than once/caching. The operating system will always read the file from disk (or network) into the page cache unless you do some very specific things (this is recommended only when you know exactly what you're doing and why). So reading the contents of the file in any other way than mmap will perform a memory-to-memory copy (unless the operating system has zero-copy mechanisms, but those are quite expensive and equivalent to mmap, except slower and work only when all the stars align just right).

Comment: @Art: Have you measured it? A friend tried to optimize the **** out of reading a file of integers (text representing the integers, ~100Mb) split in lines and the fastest was reading chunks, processing each complete line, moving what was left unprocessed to the beginning of the block and reading another chunk after that... I'd recommend testing the different alternatives

Comment: I have not measured it in this particular case, because all performance questions are best answered by benchmarks (which is what I'm recommending in my answer to this question). What I have done though is worked in an operating system in all layers between the MMU and the read and mmap system calls, including replacing a whole VM system and rebuilding a buffer cache, so I'm pretty familiar with how the I/O path works. read does pretty much the same things that mmap does, except read also needs to copy data.

Comment: Interesting aspects, @Art, thanks for the info.  I guess that copying in-memory though is so much faster than reading from a disk that benchmarks would kick this out unnoticed.  Nevertheless your point makes me stand corrected.

Comment: Well, the waiting for the disk is usually what takes the time in wall clock time. But if you look carefully at profiles of operating systems or even just normal libraries, you will very often find that copying memory from one place to another is the biggest CPU eater for a normal workload. That's why OS folks care so much about copying, that's why so much research has been put into zero-copy schemes (unfortunately most are quite impractical and most things end up using or reinventing mmap).